# framework for ASP.net to have users and transactions

Tags: asp.net, frameworks

I want to create users who then can be tied to transactions.
Think ebay, where there are users who are tied to a sell/buy.

And then I would want to have a url that points back to the transaction.

Is there an ASP.net framework that already does this?

I am thinking about having a SQL table that has the transaction and also has keys to point to users but if there is a model or framework that already does it I don't want to redo that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/whatisaspmvc) may be just the thing you need.

By using the [Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) feature included with it, you can have urls like this:

```
http://mysite.com/transactions/12345
http://mysite.com/users/12345
```

in fact, this is the framework that is used by Stack Overflow, so look up and check that url in the browser address bar - is that the sort of thing you are after?

Comment: I am familiar with that but wasn't sure how hard it is to create forms (like standard asp.net). Also is there an aSP.net mvc plug in for users and transactions? Or a good example app?